# Android - Runnable run() function is not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I am working on an android application extending activity and implementing Runnable.

The problem is that the run() function is not launched and I'm not sure if implementing Runnable make it launch automaticly as AsyncTask?

Here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, Runnable {

        ...

        @Override
        public void run() {
         // mediaPlayer is myMediaPlayer
         // progress is my SeekBar
        Log.w("Tunesto", "testabababab");
         int currentPosition = 0;
         int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
         progress.setMax(total);
         while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 return;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 return;
             }
             progress.setProgress(currentPosition);
             Log.w("MyApp", String.valueOf(currentPosition));
         }
        }
 }
```

Obviously if I launch Run fro, the UI Thread it will freeze the screen because of the sleep method, so how should I do to let the Run method to run?

Thank you!

Comment: Your activity implements Runnable? Pretty sure I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `AsyncTask` in Android.

Steps to perform:

- Create a nested class which extends `AsyncTask`
- Implement the `doInBackground` method, where your logic should reside
- Call the `execute` method on your nested class instance from where you need to call `run()`

> The fact is i'm not sure if it's possible to stop an asyntask?

You can cancel the async task using the `cancel()` method on the `AsyncTask`. Refer to Android Documentation for more details on this.

**Edit**

To move your code inside the `run()` function to an `AsyncTask`, you will put anything that is "setting up" `UI` stuff inside `onPreExecute()` such as creating a `ProgressBar`. Then put your work in such as calling `sleep()` and other things that can't be done on the `UI Thread` inside `doInBackground()`. If you need to update your seek bar you can do that in `onProgressUpdate()` by calling `publishProgress()` inside `doInBackground()`. Finally, if you need to dismiss the `ProgressBar` or do some ending `UI` stuff you will do that in `onPostExecute()`.

The reason for that explanation is because all methods of `AsyncTask` run on the `UI Thread` except for `doInBackground()`.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Vogella: Background tasks in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: The fact is i'm not sure if it's possible to stop an asyntask?

What i want it to do is just to update a seekbar.

But as the music can change I am not sure if it's better to stop the asynctask when a new music is played and start a new instance of the task or just initiate one as onCreate that will keep running waiting for a music to start?

Also, can you please make me a little exemple of an asyntask using my code? Thank you

Comment: Making a little example for you based on your present research and understanding would be like spoon feeding you. You should properly research the problem and then ask the question if you are still in doubt. So no I would not make a little example for you.

Comment: I understand, just a last question, should I insert my "run" code inside doinbackground or inside onPostExecute?

Comment: inside doInBackground, post execute comes when the running is completed and you want to do some cleanup.

Comment: Not all of that code can go in `doInBackground()`. The `UI` stuff will need to go in one of the other `AsyncTask` methods.

Comment: @codeMagic I am not that a seasoned Android developer, maybe you can add some little tit bits.

Comment: @codeMagic You mean that doInBackground won't let me update the UI?

Comment: I have added a link that will help you in understanding the core basics

Comment: @user3119384 that's exactly what I mean. Narendra, I edited to include the explanation of what I meant because it was too big for a comment. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks and yes it got overridden, but I have added the link now.

Comment: Yeah, I saw so I edited my comment. @user3119384 to answer your original question, the `run()` function doesn't "just run". You need to call `.start()` or some other method of starting it on the `Object` depending on how you are using it but I think what you were doing needed reworked somehow anyway.

Comment: @GregEnnis he can't and that is kind of rude to assume that

Comment: @GregEnnis We are here to help others, no matter what they do. We are here to help, upvotes are just cherry on the pie. Keep that nugget with you as you are just starting the journey with SO.

Comment: No you cannot! You will update in the other methods of `AsyncTask` as described in my edit to this answer.

Comment: @Greg Ennis    I have 14 rep and I need 1 more to upvote

Comment: I can't say why without seeing what you are doing but as long as its working for you, ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(this).start();
```

Although an anonymous inner class on either the handler or async would be better than making the activity itself Runnable.